# Open mail screen in own app instead of mail app

Tags: swift, xcode, email, uiapplication

I'm using the newest `Xcode` and `Swift` version.

I'm using the following code to initiate a screen to write an e-mail:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "mailto:test@example.com")!)
```

This code opens the Apple mail app, creates a new e-mail and writes `test@example.com` into the `To:` field.

Sometimes you see this "write a new e-mail" window opening as overlay in the app your initiating it from, without the Apple mail app gets opened.

How can I reach that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send an email from within the application, you can take a look at [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

You can simply instantiate this view controller, set the fields as subject, cc... and present it.

Taken from the documentation:

1. Check that the service is available (it's not available in the simulator, for example)

```
if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    print("Mail services are not available")
    return
}
```

2. Instantiate the view controller, set the delegate and present it

```
let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

// Configure the fields of the interface.
composeVC.setToRecipients(["address@example.com"])
composeVC.setSubject("Hello!")
composeVC.setMessageBody("Hello from California!", isHTML: false)

// Present the view controller modally.
self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

3. Dismiss when the mail is sent or the user cancelled

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```